# Active Directory PrincipalContext access denied when publishing to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, windows-authentication

We have a .NET Core 2.2 Web Api that uses Windows authentication. We would like to create a page where different admins can go into and add/remove users to specific AD groups. We cannot use a service account or a generic account, because depending on who is logged in, they will be able to manage different groups.

The problem is once I publish to IIS, it is the AppPools identity that is accesses AD and it's getting denied. How can I make the request to LDAP server as the logged in user, since .NET Core does not support impersonation?

```
public UserApiModel AddGroupMember(string networkId, string groupName)
{
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN"))
    {
        GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
        var canAdd = true;
        var currentUsers = group.GetMembers();

        foreach (var groupUser in currentUsers)
        {
            if (groupUser.SamAccountName == networkId)
            {
                canAdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (canAdd)
        {
            var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, networkId);

            if (usr != null)
            {
                group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "DOMAIN\\" + networkId);
                group.Save();

                return new UserApiModel
                    {
                        NetworkId = usr.SamAccountName,
                        Name = usr.DisplayName
                    };
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core doesn't support impersonation in the sense that you cannot make it automatically process an entire request under the user's credentials with a web.config setting like you could in ASP.NET.

However, you can still impersonate for a specific block of code using [`WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=netcore-3.1). There is an [Impersonation section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation) in the documentation for Windows Authentication, which describes this.

It would look something like this (in a controller, where `HttpContext` is available):

```cs
var userToImpersonate = (WindowsIdentity) HttpContext.User.Identity;

WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(userToImpersonate.AccessToken, () =>
{
    // Any code in here will run as the impersonated user
});
```